# Router Link active show previous tab active on browser back

Tags: angular

On route change by browser back, i am getting previous tab active.
But on clicking somewhere, it works fine.

1. Checking active ng-class
2. Change detection

**.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
        class="navigation-link" >
      </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/products']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
        class="navigation-link" >
      </a>
```

**.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './my-modules/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: './my-modules/products.module#ProductsModule'
      }
]
}

If i click somewhere in UI it shows correct active tab
```

Comment: what do you mean by "on clicking somewhere, it works fine"

Comment: on clicking any where on page(click event), i get correct css by routerLinkActive

Comment: You can configure RouterLinkActive by passing exact: true. This will add the classes only when the url matches the link exactly. `routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"`

Comment: i want to match all. not only exacts..

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any solutions ?